# Magento 1 get only those product collection which are not on sale in a category

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, special-price

I have created a cron which adds all products which have active special price from one specific category to another, now I want another cron to remove  products from that sale category which doesn't have active special price.
I am using this collection to get products on sale.

```
$products = $products->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','lteq'=>$current_date),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','eq'=>''),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','null'=>true)
                        ),'','left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','gteq'=>$current_date),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','eq'=>''),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','null'=>true)
                        ),'','left');

$products->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

Now I changed the condition to

```
$products = $products->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','gteq'=>$current_date),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','neq'=>''),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','null'=>false)
                        ),'','left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','lteq'=>$current_date),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','neq'=>''),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','null'=>false)
                        ),'','left');
```

But id doens't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it to work, here is the modified code

```
 $products = $products->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','gteq'=>$current_date),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','lteq'=>$current_date)

                        ),'','left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','neq'=>''),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','neq'=>'')

                        ),'','left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(


                            array('attribute'=>'special_to_date','notnull'=>true),
                            array('attribute'=>'special_from_date','notnull'=>true)
                        ),'','left');
```